# Building listview from data obtained by parsing a webpage

Tags: java, android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am a total newbie to android so my question might sound very immature. I want to make a list view of the table displayed on this page:
http://www.medicalmnemonics.com/cgi-bin/return_browse.cfm?discipline=Rheumatology%20%2F%20Allergy&browse=1

I tried parsing with Jsoup but couldn't figure out how to do it. Could someone please explain how can I do it using Jsoup or any other parser?

Comment: Does the data on that webpage change often?

Comment: Have you try read the documentation of [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

To get data from the tag use the below code.

```
<strong>Joint pain causes</strong>

public void getDataurl()
{

    URL url;
    try {

        url = new URL("http://www.medicalmnemonics.com/cgi-bin/return_browse.cfm?discipline=Rheumatology%20%2F%20Allergy&browse=1");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000);

        Elements elements = doc.select("strong");

        for( Element e : elements )
        {

          System.out.println(e.text());
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but my app crashes when I run it! I tried everything, set the permission to use internet, clean project, shit+alt+o to organize and many more things mentioned online but it seems like it wont work.

Comment: post your code and have you added jsoup.jar to your libs folder?